# Loop and bind props to different components

Tags: vue.js

I have 3 different child components that all need exactly the same props and custom event listeners.

```
Vue.component('parent',{
    template:
        `<div>
            <component1 :prop1="prop1" :prop2="prop2" v-on:some-event="someEventHandler" />
            <component2 :prop1="prop1" :prop2="prop2" v-on:some-event="someEventHandler" />
            <component3 :prop1="prop1" :prop2="prop2" v-on:some-event="someEventHandler" />
        </div>`
})


var testMixin = {
    props:['prop1','prop2'],
    template: `<div>{{prop1}}</div>`
}

Vue.component('component1',{
    mixins:[testMixin]
    ///custom code
})

Vue.component('component2',{
    mixins:[testMixin]
    ///custom code
})

Vue.component('component3',{
    mixins:[testMixin]
    ///custom code
})
```

Is there any way i can stop repeating myself in the parent template? Can i register components locally and then somehow perform a `v-for` on them to bind props/events?

Also, where should i declare non-reactive data?

Comment: Can you give any explanation as to why you need 3 different components?

Comment: They are d3.js graphs that display different data sets, so i need custom d3 logic per component to process the data. The child components all emit the same events that i handle in the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? Using [dynamic components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components).

```
var testMixin = {
    props:['prop1','prop2'],
    template: `<div>{{prop1}}</div>`
}

const comp1 = Vue.extend({
  mixins:[testMixin],
})
const comp2 = Vue.extend({
  mixins:[testMixin],
})
const comp3 = Vue.extend({
  mixins:[testMixin],
})

Vue.component("parent",{
  template:"<div><component v-for='comp in components' :is='comp' :prop1='prop1' :prop2='prop2'></component>",
  data(){
    return {
      prop1: "prop1",
      prop2: "some other prop",
      components: [comp1, comp2, comp3]
    }
  }
})
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/xqzRYZ?editors=1010).

Comment: Yes, exactly like that. Thanks